Which proof is more general? (Derivative of Series is Series of Derivatives)
Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be open and $(f_n)_n$ a sequence in $C_b^1(\Omega, \mathbb{C})$ (the space of $C^1$-functions $g$ such that $g$ and $g'$ are bounded). Equipping this space with the uniform norm makes it a Banach space. So if we assume $\sum_{k =0}^{\infty} \| f_n\|_{L^\infty} < \infty$ and $\sum_{k =0}^{\infty} \| f_n'\|_{L^\infty} < \infty$, then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n $ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f'_n$ converge in $C_b^1$ and $C_b$ respectively (where the convergence is with respect to the uniform norm). The goal is to prove that $\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n \right)' = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} f_n'$.
The proof provided in the text I am following uses the "Differentiation-Under-Integral-Sign" theorem from measure theory, applied to the counting measure. However, I'm wondering whether it can instead be proven by using that theorem from real analysis that says
$$
u_n\to u \text{ uniformly and } u_n' \to v \text{ uniformly} \implies u'=v
$$
for differentiable functions $u_n$ defined on a closed interval. It should be possible to apply this theorem to a small closed interval around every point in $\Omega$ with $u_n = \sum_{k=0}^n f_k$.

Is there any reason why this proof wouldn't work?
Are there any reasons to prefer the other proof (using the "Differentiation-Under-Integral-Sign" theorem)? Would that allow for a more general statement, like dropping boundedness in the hypothesis or extending to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Edit: The text I'm using is a script for an introductory lecture on Hilbert spaces and Fourier theory I'm taking. This little exercise was in the lead-up to the theorems that relate regularity of functions with the behaviour of their Fourier coefficients. This includes a theorem that asserts: if the Fourier coefficients of a function are sufficiently summable, then the function belongs to some $C^h_{\text{periodic}}$. In this proof, the above theorem from real analysis was used (instead of the measure theoretic one). Thus I'm wondering why the same strategy wasn't used for the exercise presented before.

It would also help to know what text you are using---generally speaking authors build up the theory in a particular way, and later theorems will depend only on the theorems proved earlier in the text.  The author may have chosen the proof they presented simply because that particular proof fits within the theory has they have developed it.

Yes the proof works. No you cannot drop boundedness. There are any number of reasons the author may have for giving the other proof. Most likely, it is just the one that came to mind when they were putting this together. For simple results like this, there are usually mutiple approaches that are known, and which you might choose mostly depends on what you've been thinking about recently.
